# what is a projection in LINQ, as in .Select()

Tags: linq, projection

I typically do mobile app development, which doesn't always have .Select. However, I've seen this used a bit, but I don't really know what it does or how it's doing whatever it does. It is anything like

```
    from a in list select a // a.Property // new Thing { a.Property}
```

I'm asking because when I've seen code using .Select(), I was a bit confused by what it was doing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`.Select()` is from method syntax for LINQ, `select` in your code `from a in list select a` is for query syntax. Both are same, query syntax compiles into method syntax.

You may see: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

**Projection:**

[Projection Operations - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546168.aspx)

> Projection refers to the operation of transforming an object into a
>   new form that often consists only of those properties that will be
>   subsequently used. By using projection, you can construct a new type
>   that is built from each object. You can project a property and perform
>   a mathematical function on it. You can also project the original
>   object without changing it.

You may also see: 
[LINQ Projection](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LinqProjection.aspx)

> The process of transforming the results of a query is called
>   projection. You can project the results of a query after any filters
>   have been applied to change the type of the collection that is
>   returned.

[Example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546168.aspx)

```
List<string> words = new List<string>() { "an", "apple", "a", "day" };
var query = from word in words
            select word.Substring(0, 1);
```

In the above example only first character from each string instance is selected / projected.

You can also select some fields from your collection and create an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) or an instance of existing class, that process is called projection.

```
from a in list select new { ID = a.Id}
```

In the above code field `Id` is projected into an anonymous type ignoring other fields. Consider that your list has an object of type `MyClass` defined like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can project the `Id` and `Name` to an anonymous type like:

Query Syntax:

```
var result = from a in list
             select new
                 {
                     ID = a.Id,
                     Name = a.Name,
                 };
```

Method Syntax

```
var result = list.Select(r => new { ID = r.Id, Name = r.Name });
```

You can also project result to a new class. Consider you have a class like:

```
    class TemporaryHolderClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can do:

Query Syntax:

```
 var result = from a in list
             select new TemporaryHolderClass
                 {
                     Id = a.Id,
                     Name = a.Name,
                 };
```

Method Syntax:

```
var result = list.Select(r => new TemporaryHolderClass  
                            { 
                                Id = r.Id, 
                                Name = r.Name 
                            });
```

You can also project to the same class, provided you are not trying to project to classes generated/created for LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

My summary is it takes results (or a subset of results) and allows you to quickly restructure it for use in the local context.

> The select clause produces the results of the query and specifies the
>   "shape" or type of each returned element. For example, you can specify
>   whether your results will consist of complete Customer objects, just
>   one member, a subset of members, or some completely different result
>   type based on a computation or new object creation.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx

There are a lot of possible uses for this but one is taking a complex object which of many other contains a property that is a string -- say `Name` -- and allows you to return an enumeration with just the entries of `Name`. I believe you can also do the opposite -- use that property ( for example) and create / return new type of object while passing in a property or properties.

Answer (score -1):

It means "mapping". Map each element of a sequence to a transformed sequence. I hadn't comprehended its meaning before I looked at the image.

> Where does the meaning of the word come from?

Simply, math! https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Projection.html

[image]

Comment: It seems you missed the question is about LINQ projection.

Comment: @CLS no i m pretty sure