# Calling controller Action method using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am trying to call a controller action method inside the lambda expression like below.

Here `dtImporteddata` is my `DataTable`

```
public class DepartmentController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection, int ParentDepartmentID)
    {
       return view();
    }
}


   dtImporteddata.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => new DepartmentController().Create(new FormCollection{ 
                {"ParentDepartmentID","57"},
                {"DepartmentPrefix",r["Prefix"].ToString()},
                {"DepartmentID","0"},
                {"IsSpecialDepartment",null},
                {"Description",r["Description"].ToString()},
                {"Name",r["Name"].ToString()},
                {"LocationIDs.$.PackedValue","4;;;"}
             }, 0)).ToList();
```

if i write like above the `Create()` method is getting called perfectly but if i remove `ToList()` then the `Create()` is not getting called.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Create is my Action method in the controller

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `Select` method actually doesn't do that much. It starts doing something when you iterate over its result.

That said, the `ToList` method does iterate over the iterator returned from `Select`, hence it executes your lambda expression.

I guess you want to pick up the result and do something with it, if so, assign it to a variable and iterate over it:

```
foreach(var row in dtImporteddata.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(...))
{
    // do something with row
}
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ methods can be split into two camps: those which always return a result (eg, `FirstOrDefault`) and those which *project* a different form of what's being given to them. You can think of these projection methods as performing filtering operations.

See [what is a projection in LINQ, as in .Select()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251976/what-is-a-projection-in-linq-as-in-select)

Anyway, to answer your question, LINQ doesn't always perform the operation that you might think it's performing. In many cases LINQ uses subsequent operations to add filtering (or modify the projection) and only when you *resolve* the method call to a result are the calls executed.

I suspect that this is the case here. Without the `ToList` call you're only *building* the set of instructions, and only when you call `ToList` are these instructions resolved to a result.

If you're not actually bothered about the functionality offered by a `List<DataRow>` and you simply want an enumerable result, consider using `ToArray` as it has less overhead than `ToList`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest abstracting the create functionality in a reusable component, that both the controller and your lambda can use. For example, you could create a class that has a method with the following signature:

```
public void CreateDepartment(Department newDepartment)
```

The `Department` class could probably expose the same fields as the `FormCollection`.

You could the use the new method directly in LINQ like so:

```
dtImporteddata.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList()
              .ForEach(r => CreateDepartment(
                                new Department {
                                                   Name = r.Name,
                                                   ....//rest of the properties
                                                }));
```

In this way, you would also be able to call the same method within the Create action.