# EntityFreamwork full entity and lite entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have table users

user table :

Id, Name , firstName ,  password , email , address , dateofBrith

i want to create two entity for user table one lite and other full

```
[Table("user")]
public class LiteUser 
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int firstName{get;set;}
}
```

second entity

```
public class fullUser : LiteUser
{   
       public date dateofBrith {get;set;}
       public string password {get;set;}
       public string email {get;set;}
       public string address {get;set;}

}
```

> but not I get error about  no column discriminator

is possible to do somthing like my entity are same but one have more filed then the other entity

thank you in advance for help

Comment: Map your Full user to your table.  If you don't need all the fields in the course of whatever you are coding, use a [projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251976/what-is-a-projection-in-linq-as-in-select) to only return the fields you need.

Comment: @Fran Great reference to projection.  If you're not in the mood for LINQ, you can always map the EF entity (full) into a DTO you call LiteUser.  One EF entity per table, by design.

Comment: @JohnWhite >One EF entity per table< is not accurate.  You can map [entities across tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) table per type, you can have entities with inheritance that live within a [single table] (https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) table per heirarchy.  But this are more involved scenarios.

Comment: @Fran in EF6 and back, yes.  I actually have that running in several scenarios.  In EF Core, no, and I am not aware of plans to add it.  For this OP, it was the simplest response to address his scenario.  A different scenario would require a more complex, nuanced response.  But thanks for the additional links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use table splitting which is when you map a single table to two or more entities.  The difference with your requested solution is that the "additional" properties in the "full" configuration will be represented by another entity type.  Example (for EF Core; EF6 will be very similar):

```
public class SplitTablePrincipal
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PrincipalProperty { get; set; }
    // principal entity has a nav property to the dependent entity
    public virtual SplitTableDependent Dependent { get; set; }
}

public class SplitTableDependent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DependentProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SplitTablePricipalConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SplitTablePrincipal>
{
    public void Configure( EntityTypeBuilder<SplitTablePrincipal> builder )
    {
        //builder.HasKey( pe => pe.Id );
        // establish 1:? relationship w/ shared primary key
        builder.HasOne( pe => pe.Dependent )
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<SplitTableDependent>( de => de.Id ); // FK is PK
        builder.ToTable( "YourTableName" );
    }
}

public class SplitTableDependentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SplitTableDependent>
{
    public void Configure( EntityTypeBuilder<SplitTableDependent> builder )
    {
        //builder.HasKey( de => de.Id );
        // map dependent entity to same table as principal
        builder.ToTable( "YourTableName" ); // same table name
    }
}
```

You only need to include a `DbSet` for the `SplitTablePrincipal` entity type in your `DbContext`.  When querying, the `Dependent` property will not be populated by default (your "lite" configuration); you would need to eager load the property for the "full" data configuration via `.Include( stp => stp.Dependent )`.  You could also lazy load or explicitly load the `Dependent` property further down the line should you so choose.  For example:

```
dbContext.Entry( principalEntity ).Reference( p => p.Dependent ).Load();
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.  You can only define one entity to one table.  Instead, you'd have to do a manual .Select off of the full entity to return a custom "Lite" entry because EF needs to know all the columns that tie to a specific table from the start.

Edit: The only way around this would be to create a view and map to that instead.

Comment: This is incorrect; table splitting allows one to map multiple entities to a single table but not in the fashion requested in the question

Comment: Huh, learned something new.  So you can have two entities point to the same table but only if they don't share any columns.  I don't see why you'd ever really want to do that since you could just as easily sub-select the data you really want and the query would respond correctly.  Instead, you'd have to do an Include on a "sub" table that is really itself which could get confusing quickly.  at the end of the day, I'm starting to lean towards using EF for saving and then Dapper for all my gets since it is so much faster - but I also like writing SQL. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel points out, a table can be associated to a single entity definition, outside of Table Per Hierarchy inheritance, which isn't what you are looking for.

This was an old trick I used with NHibernate which isn't supported in EF.

With EF you can utilize Linq and ViewModels to avoid the need of Lite vs. Full models.

Given:

```
//Entity
public class User
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int firstName{get;set;}
   public date dateofBrith {get;set;}
   public string password {get;set;}
   public string email {get;set;}
   public string address {get;set;}
}

// View Models...
public class LiteUserViewModel 
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int firstName{get;set;}
} 

public class FullUserViewModel : LiteUserViewModel
{   
   public date dateofBrith {get;set;}
   public string password {get;set;}
   public string email {get;set;}
   public string address {get;set;}
}
```

Querying..

```
//Give me a list of lite data..
var viewModels = context.Users
    .Where(x => x.DateOfBirth < startDate)
    .Select(x => new LiteUserViewModel
    {
       UserId = x.UserId,
       Name = x.Name,
       FirstName = x.FirstName
    }).ToList();

// Give me a full user.
var viewModel = context.Users
    .Where(x => x.UserId = userId)
    .Select(x => new FullUserViewModel
    {
       UserId = x.UserId,
       // ... etc ...
    }).SingleOrDefault();
```

You can leverage libraries like AutoMapper to handle mapping entity to view model. In cases where you just want to inspect data you don't need to define a view model / DTO, just use an anonymous type. The end result is the same in that EF will execute an optimized query to just return back the data you want rather than entire entities. You can optimize view models to flatten down hierarchical data using this technique. You do need to ensure that any methods or transformations in the `.Select()` are pure and EF compatible because EF will attempt to translate and pass those to SQL. More complex transformations should be done in the view model itself, or utilize an anonymous type select of the raw data, followed by a ToList/Single/etc. then .Select() into the view model with appropriate transformations via Linq2Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
[Table("user")]
public class LiteUser 
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int firstName{get;set;}
}

public class fullUser : LiteUser
{   
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public date dateofBrith {get;set;}
   public string password {get;set;}
   public string email {get;set;}
   public string address {get;set;}

}
```

> Use primary key `public int ID {get;set;}` value in the derived class